# pharo smalltalk, blocking dialog and parents windows

Tags: user-interface, dialog, window, smalltalk, pharo

I'm doing an application in Pharo. And I am designing some GUI with UIBuilder.

I am manipulating windows, and these windows creates others windows (or dialogs).

My question is how to do for when I close the Main window, all the other secondaries close too.
And how to do when a dialog pops up, to block the program until the dialog is closed.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second question,

> And how to do when a dialog pops up, to block the program until the dialog is closed,

are you aware of `#openModal: aSystemWindow`?

You could try this in a Workspace:

```
|window1 window2|
window1 := SystemWindow new openInWorld.
window2 := SystemWindow new.
window1 openModal: window2.
```